# Usage of "so to" in the place of "to" as part of infinitive construction

Tags: expressions, word-usage, infinitives

Example:

> We make wine by hand in small lots and taste the wines constantly so to profit from its constant change.

I would normally drop the "so" and phrase it like "we do it to profit"

Are both correct?

Bonus: would "as to" or "so as to" be the same thing?

Comment: Not a preposition there.

Comment: A conjunction then?

Comment: It is part of the infinitive construction.

Comment: 'So to V' means 'to V to the extent that', as in  'and the widespread diffusion of ideas have made it necessary for one group so to depend upon the other and so to profit by the achievements of the other that ...', which is quite different. 'So as to' and 'to' in these constructions (= 'in order to') are largely synonymous. The quote is from ...

Comment: [The Story of the Negro Retold](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=R_90Km6cmrsC&pg=PA441&lpg=PA441&dq=%22so+to+profit%22&source=bl&ots=MY7yVwrSEk&sig=Av6Abhz0XqRdRN3u2D8UNZPWLVY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwA2oVChMI7dvmi9vTxwIVpPByCh2AFQMJ#v=onepage&q=%22so%20to%20profit%22&f=false).

Comment: This appears to be a typo or an earo of _so as to_, which is a version of _in order to_, introducing a purpose infinitive. Both the _so_ and the _as_ are necessary, however; _so to_ only occurs in idioms like _so to say_ or _and so to bed_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We make wine by hand in small lots and taste the wines constantly so to profit from its constant change.

There is no strictly grammatical reason but the following is what we actually say or don't say in English.

**Not used**

We make wine by hand in small lots and taste the wines constantly so to profit from its constant change.

We make wine by hand in small lots and taste the wines constantly as to profit from its constant change.

**Normal English**

We make wine by hand in small lots and taste the wines constantly to profit from its constant change.

We make wine by hand in small lots and taste the wines constantly in order to profit from its constant change.

We make wine by hand in small lots and taste the wines constantly so as to profit from its constant change.